# Denied permission of a symbolic link to a shared folder

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop, cygwin, symbolic-link

I use `Microsoft Remote Desktop` to connect my Mac to Microsoft Azure VM. I follow this thread (`apple.stackexchange.com/a/140506/20747`) to share a Mac folder named `Music` with the VM. It works fine, here is the result of [net use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJID1.png).

In the VM, I need to access this folder by GNU of Cygwin, which looks similar to a command prompt. By following this thread (`serverfault.com/questions/656675/cannot-map-drive-letter-to-redirected-folder-when-using-microsoft-remote-desktop`), I did `MKLINK /D C:\Music \\tsclient\Music` to successfully build a symbolic link.

However, when I try to enter the link by `cd C:/Music` in GNU of Cygwin, I got an error `-bash: cd: Music: Permission denied`; Moreover, i cannot click into the folder in [file explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTExp.png) anymore.

Does anyone know how to assign the right permission to the symbolic link so that I could `cd` it in a command prompt?